# How far do you need to play before Twitch viewers can join your cult?

Tags: twitch, cult-of-the-lamb

A friend is playing Cult of the Lamb with [Twitch integration enabled](https://www.ign.com/wikis/cult-of-the-lamb/How_Twitch_Integration_Works). They've been playing for a while, but we haven't seen any opportunity for viewers to join their cult or vote on events. The overlay on Twitch says the streamer has no followers in their cult.

Are Twitch integrated events disabled during the tutorial? If so, how long does the streamer need to play before viewers can join their cult?

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow these [activation steps](https://www.ign.com/wikis/cult-of-the-lamb/Cult_of_the_Lamb_New_Twitch_Integrations_Update) correctly?

- Visit the Creator Dashboard
- Select the Extensions tab from the left-hand menu
- From the Discovery tab, search Companion of the Lamb in the search bar
- Select the Add button next to Companion of the Lamb from your search results
- Set up your Channel Points rewards
- Set up Follower message moderation options
- Set up Premium follower skins options
- Select the "Activate" button in the bottom right corner, and choose which Overlay to set this Extension as

Afterwards, the Cult of the Lamb twitch integrations will automatically be included in the stream.

Comment: The streamer was able to fix it by restarting the plugin